# What does ‘::’ (double colon) do in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, syntax

The documentation of some JavaScript APIs shows the following snippets as an example of how to invoke some function:

```
<button type="button" onClick="foo.DoIt(72930)">Click</button>

<button type="button" onClick="foo.DoIt(42342::37438)">Click</button>
```

`::` is obviously used here to allow either one or two arguments to be passed to the function.

**What does `::` do in JavaScript?**

And how does the function know if one or two values were passed? How does it read them?

---

On closer look, the examples show other weird stuff like

```
<button type="button" onClick="foo.Bar(72//893)">Click</button>

<button type="button" onClick="foo.Qux(425;1,34::)">Click</button>
```

At least the `//` looks just wrong.

So I guess it's not some fancy new syntax that I'm not aware of, but maybe the examples are just missing quotes around a single string argument.

Comment: AFAIK, that's a typo. The double-colon in that use makes no sense.

Comment: can you tell us more about the javascript API you are using..

Comment: Sorry, the API and it's documentation are not publicly available, so I can't provide a link.

Comment: see also [JavaScript double colon (bind operator)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31220078/javascript-double-colon-bind-operator)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Nothing. It is a syntax error.

```
>>> alert(42342::37438)
SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list
```

Comment: Yep, unless for some ungodly reason said developer is actually parsing the onclick attribute value with `document.getElementsByTagName('button')[0].getAttribute('onclick')` and extracting that information, that is an invalid ECMAScript expression.

Comment: @Brann — It doesn't appear to be valid in the context given in the question.

Comment: @Pawel — No it isn't. See my previous comment. See the context of the question.

Answer (score 283):

It was certainly not the case at the time of your question, but right now `::` is a valid ES7 operator. It's actually a shortcut for `bind`.

```
::foo.bar
```

is equivalent to

```
foo.bar.bind(foo)
```

[See an explanation here](http://blog.jeremyfairbank.com/javascript/javascript-es7-function-bind-syntax/) for examples:

Comment: If I'm reading that correctly, then it isn't valid in the context given in the question. The LHS and RHS of the `::` in the question are Numbers.

Comment: This is the answer I was looking for when I Googled for what :: means though! Thanks

Comment: This answer has nothing to do with the question, because (1) ES7, which is published in June 2016, doesn't contain `::` operator; (2) `::` operator is only a stage 0 proposal currently, which is highly probable of being changed or removed; (3) In the context of the question, it is not a valid `::` operator syntax, and even the correct syntax will not work in any current major browsers.

Comment: The question title doesn't match the question body, although, this answer suits the title question, in my case what I was looking for.

Answer (score 7):

`::` has nothing to do with the number of parameters. You can do that already in JavaScript with a normal comma:

```
function SomeFunction(param1, param2) {
   //...
}

SomeFunction('oneParam'); // Perfectly legal
```

Also, based on Tzury Bar Yochay's answer, are you sure you're not looking at something like the following?

```
$('this::is all one::parameter'); // jQuery selector
```

Comment: I guess you're right and it's missing the quotes. I will submit a bug report to the author :)

Answer (score 2):

In which example did you see that? So far, JavaScript does not have a double colon operator!

The double colon replaced the single-colon selectors for pseudo-elements in CSS3 to make an explicit distinction between pseudo-classes and pseudo-elements. But that is CSS3, not JavaScript! Not At ALL!

Comment: Given this, it sounds like perhaps he's looking at a jquery selector and omitted the quotes around the parameter.

Comment: probably. in any case, this question drew far more attention than I thought it would.

Answer (score 1):

It must be a typo for

```
<button type="button" onClick="foo.DoIt('72930')">Click</button>

<button type="button" onClick="foo.DoIt('42342::37438')">Click</button>
```

Answer (score 1):

It could be using ECMAScript for XML ([ECMA-357 standard](http://www.ecma-international.org/publications/standards/Ecma-357.htm)) which would imply the double quotes are a XPath operator.

See [ECMAScript for XML](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ECMAScript_for_XML)

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps it's a typo, and the whole thing is expected to be in quotes.

Answer (score 0):

I am guessing that the parameter list for foo.DoIt() is generated by code, and one the values was empty.