# What does ‘::’ (double colon) do in javascript for events?

Tags: javascript, jscript

I saw this code and I'm scratching my head trying to decide how it works.

```
<SCRIPT LANGUAGE=javascript> 

     function SpeechMikeControl::SPMEventButton(lDeviceID, EventId) {
        alert("lDeviceID=" + lDeviceID + ", EventId=" + EventId);
     }

</SCRIPT>
```

double colon?  This is from using a philips speech mike from a web page.

Any idea what this double colon means?  It seems like a syntax error to me but it works! (at least in IE).

Comment: possible duplicate of [What does ‘::’ (double colon) do in javascript?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1520360/what-does-double-colon-do-in-javascript)

Comment: Not a dup. I found the other link. It's not related to my question.

Comment: I don't see why it's not a dup. Your code snippet above gives a syntax error as well

Comment: What IE does it work in? Not in IE8 at least.

Comment: I agree it's not a dup -- both questions may ask about double-colon in JS, but the syntax usage in the two is significantly different.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I've been able to find an obscure reference in some scanned manual from [Microsoft Office Infopath 2003](http://books.google.com/books?id=ZY9h8FjCkewC&pg=PA25&lpg=PA25&dq=%2bjscript%20double%20colon&source=bl&ots=AWq1RzBI8E&sig=6lkIuj5mwa8sEsMwa72yFFeksyo&hl=es&ei=YWytTfvrEsWZ8QOrptnyAQ&sa=X&oi=book_result&ct=result&resnum=1&sqi=2&ved=0CBcQ6AEwAA#v=onepage&q=%2bjscript%20double%20colon&f=false). It appears to be a `JScript` syntax:

> a double colon is used as separator
>   between the script ID and the event
>   name

My guess is that's not part (or no longer part) of Internet explorer's ECMAScript implementation but it belongs (or used to belong) to Microsoft Office's implementation.

Comment: Thanks. That seems right.  I guess IE is falling back on JScript when it sees this construct.

Comment: A more relevant reference would be to [Scripting Events](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms974564.aspx), where this syntax is as described in [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/7196576/111794) answer.

Answer (score 6):

This is an extension to the Javascript language implemented by Microsoft. It's purpose is to specify an event handler for a COM object referenced on the page.  `SpeechMikeControl` is the globally-scoped name of the COM (and/or ActiveX) object:

- either with an `OBJECT` or some other element, which has an `id` property of `SpeechMikeControl`, or
- a global variable `SpeechMikeControl` declared somewhere previously in the Javascript

`SPMEventButton` is the name of the COM event which will be raised by the `SpeechMikeControl` object under who-knows-what circumstances.

The double colon is an instruction to connect the function body as a handler to the control's event.

Answer (score 3):

Pretty sure it's a syntax error

Comment: @Dan it doesn't work. You're just not seeing the error for some reason. Maybe IE is hiding them - look out for the yellow exclamation mark in the bottom left corner in IE8

Comment: It is a syntax error only to the beholder. While searching for some answers, it seems it is indeed JScript syntax...

Comment: It is not a syntax error under IE. See [Scripting Events](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms974564.aspx), [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41713117/acitvex-event-handlers-in-an-hta-using-javascript), and the answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/7196576/111794).

Answer (score 3):

As mentioned in this answer of [What does ‘::’ (double colon) do in javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31180878/496103)

`::` is a ES2016 operator that is shorthand for bind.  This answer intends to assist those that have encountered `::` since the ES2016 spec, however, does not apply to the context in which this question was asked.

Comment: The question was asked in 2011.

Comment: Yes, this question likely comes up in search engine results quite often now that ES2016 is here and uses `::`.  As I mentioned above, this answer does not refer to the original question but intends to inform those looking for the ES2016 implementation.

Comment: The answer has no real bearing on the question, because the syntax in the question is a function declaration, and cannot possibly have anything to do with ES2016 binding.

Comment: I appreciate this answer, as I was searching for what `::` does in regards to ES2016.  Searching for "what does :: do" is difficult, as `::` isn't very search friendly, so again, I find value in this answer.

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty certain that's not valid Javascript syntax.

If it works in IE but not other browsers, it could possibly be that IE is treating it as another scripting language (maybe VBScript? although I don't recall that having a double colon operator either? Not sure what other language it could be though.)

Comment: IE runs JScript, not "standard" Javascript hence it recognizes more things than you'd think :)

Comment: It does indeed have special meaning in Javascript under IE and WSH. See [Scripting Events](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms974564.aspx), [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41713117/acitvex-event-handlers-in-an-hta-using-javascript), and the answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/7196576/111794).

Answer (score 0):

The question may not be a duplicate of [What does ‘::’ (double colon) do in javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1520360/what-does-double-colon-do-in-javascript), but the answer is: it is a syntax error.

In the following:

```
function SpeechMikeControl::SPMEventButton(lDeviceID, EventId) {
```

the keyword *function* in the global context at the start of an expression indicates a function declaration. Following **must** be an identifier that is the function name. After the name must be an opening grouping operator '(', formal parameter list and closing grouping operator ')'. So between *function* and *()* can only be a single identifier of allowable characters (that isn't a reserved word, or future reserved word, but that isn't an issue here).

The ":" (colon) character is a punctuator and can not appear in an identifier. So it *must* cause a syntax error if the code is treated as javascript.

Perhaps IE has an extension to the language, I don't know ECMAScript well enough to know if that is permissible, but I'd expect not since it **will** break other implementations.

Comment: It is not a syntax error under IE. See [Scripting Events](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms974564.aspx), [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41713117/acitvex-event-handlers-in-an-hta-using-javascript), and the answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/7196576/111794).

Comment: @ZevSpitz—the question is tagged javascript, not JScript. It would be more helpful if you posted an answer with versions of JScript that support it and the relevant versions of IE, as well as whether it's supported by Microsoft Edge.

Comment: _the question is tagged javascript, not JScript_ Well, that's easily fixed. :) But, I misspoke; it's valid under Microsoft JScript (AFAIK all versions) which can be used in multiple environments -- IE, WSH, classic ASP.