# Double colons in function declaration in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, activex

Today I found this code snippet:

```html
<object ID="FF" CLASSID="clsid:guid" CODEBASE="url" VIEWASTEXT></object>
<object ID="FileSaver" CLASSID="clsid:guid" CODEBASE="url" VIEWASTEXT></object>
…
<script language="javascript">
    function FileSaver::OnFinished(Status){…}
    function FF::OnFinished(Status){…}
</script>
```

I can't find *anything* relevant to explain this syntax. Is it really javascript? Is it correct? If not, how the code should look like?

This is a single page without external script links.
Note that function declarations are directly inside `<script>` block.

Comment: And just like that, SO borked the code snippet. Not cool.

Comment: after pasting in the code, select it all, and hit the `{}` button in the editor toolbar. Viola! The [language hint](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/981/syntax-highlighting-language-hints/75019#75019) isn't necessary, but sometimes helps.

Comment: possible duplicate of [What does ‘::’ (double colon) do in javascript for events?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5715239/what-does-double-colon-do-in-javascript-for-events)

Comment: @sarnold I did! And the preview was fine.

Comment: @13x, ah, I see, so you did -- but you needed a blank line after the `<!-- language: lang-html -->` hint. (It took me longer than I care to admit to discover that the blank line was mandatory. :)

Comment: @13xforever: Might I suggest you post the answer as an actual answer to your own question? That's perfectly acceptable :-)

Comment: @James Wiseman: Yeah, I tried it the last time, but couldn't (there was a time limit restriction).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Thanks for everyone who looked into this.

Anyway, just as one could expect, not after five minutes after submitting the question, I found [How to handle an ActiveX event in Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/150814/how-to-handle-an-activex-event-in-javascript) question about ActiveX callback handlers in IE, so it answers the main part of the question. As well, as the question that @outis has linked.

But I can't find any documentation on MSDN and that's troubling.

**Conclusion**: this is IE-specific ECMAScript extension for event handler declaration.

Comment: There is [this article](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms974564.aspx) on MSDN. Also, I've written a [library](https://github.com/zspitz/activex-js-events) to work the many limitations of these event handlers.