# Java Method reference operator(double colon) equivalent in typescript

Tags: typescript, rxjs

What is the equivalent of Java double colon operator in typescript(if there's any):

```
stream.forEach( System.out::println(s));
```

EDIT: 
I know it's doable with certain functions like:

```
stream.forEach(console.log);
stream.filter(Boolean);
```

But when I use other functions e.g. BehaviorSubject "next" my code breaks. I don't know what qualifies those other two to be called by reference. I'd like to have something like:

```
stream.pipe(someSubject.next);
```

Instead of:

```
stream.pipe(value => someSubject.next(value));
```

Comment: Are you sure that it's `stream.forEach( System.out::println(s));`  and not `stream.forEach( System.out::println);` ?

Answer (score 6):

Okay, so I did a bit of searching and there is a double colon operator in JScript, which was Microsoft's implementation of JavaScript:

> a double colon is used as separator between the script ID and the event name
>
> My guess is that's not part (or no longer part) of Internet explorer's ECMAScript implementation but it belongs (or used to belong) to Microsoft Office's implementation

[What does ‘::’ (double colon) do in javascript for events?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5715239/what-does-double-colon-do-in-javascript-for-events)

Which was a really cool find, but I've never seen a double colon operator being used in TS or ECMAScript.
You can use lambda expressions
`[].forEach((item: any) => console.log(item))`

but I'm pretty sure JS or TS doesn't have a  wrapper for a lambda expression like Java does.

EDIT: I also found this [What does ‘::’ (double colon) do in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1520360/what-does-double-colon-do-in-javascript/31180878#31180878) after a little more searching and it is also a valid ES7 operator as syntactic sugar for bind: http://blog.jeremyfairbank.com/javascript/javascript-es7-function-bind-syntax/

Although it doesn't behave the same way as Java's :: operator.