# javascript syntax function, unable to figure out its functionality?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Has anyone ever come across a function syntax like given below in javascript or jquery.
It is there in my project and I am not able to figure out what it is.

```
 function a::b(arg1, arg2)
 {}
```

Comment: that is a syntax error

Comment: My developer console just says "Syntax Error". Are you sure this is JavaScript?

Comment: This is invalid syntax for ECMAScript 5.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1520360/what-does-double-colon-do-in-javascript

Comment: it seems c/c++ like syntax

Comment: _"in Javascript or jQuery"_ - note that jQuery doesn't have its own special syntax; it can't, it's a collection of functions written in Javascript.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No, that's invalid javascript. So if you ever come across such syntax you have 2 choices:

- If you are the author of this code, fix it.
- If you are not the author (like you saw it in a plugin or something) notify the author so that he can fix it

Comment: Verified that this does not exist in the ES6 specification draft either, they use it to indicate parts of the grammar bnf but it has no meaning except for that and is not a valid language construct. I think OP might be seeing typescript or some macro or something

Answer (score 2):

you can either use normal function

function xyz(){}
or
you can use singleton

xyz:function(){}

Comment: Thanks everyone, even I was thinking so. That's invalid syntax. Never seen that before :)

Answer (score 0):

This is invalid javascript syntax:

[image]

Comment: I don't think this answer adds anything over what Darin said over 5 minutes ago.

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum And the answer doesn't add to the comments. I do not think this warrants a downvote.

Comment: Downvotes do not indicate I like or dislike you or your answer. I don't think the answer is bad, or incorrect or anything like that. Rather, downvotes indicate usefulness, or lack of it. Downvotes indicate "This answer is not useful", and upvotes indicate "This answer is useful". I did not find it useful (since it pretty much says what Darin said earlier, only less elaborately) so I down-voted it. Please do not take any offense in that. Your effort is recognized and I know you were trying to help, this is part of the reason down votes only cost 2 rep and up-votes generate 10.

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum Thank you. No offense taken of course. It is the Internets after all.