# JavaScript double colon (bind operator)

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-harmony, ecmascript-next

As you know, there is a proposal for a shortcut for `.bind()` function, so you can write:

```
::this.handleStuff
```

and it will work like that in es5:

```
this.handleStuff.bind(this)
```

My question is: will it be possible to pass arguments this way?

I mean a way of writing this with the aforementioned shortcut:

```
this.handleStuff.bind(this, 'stuff')
```

It's a pretty common pattern in React, so it would be nice to shorten it a little.

Comment: Are you talking about partial application?

Comment: Seem like a good idea for yet another spec proposal.

Answer (score 165, accepted):

No. The [bind operator](http://wiki.ecmascript.org/doku.php?id=strawman:bind_operator) ([spec proposal](https://github.com/tc39/proposal-bind-operator)) comes in two flavours:

- Method extraction

  ```
  ::obj.method     ≡ obj.method.bind(obj)
  ```
- "virtual method" calls

  ```
  obj::function    ≡ function.bind(obj)
  obj::function(…) ≡ function.call(obj, …)
  ```

Neither of them feature [partial application](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partial_application). For what you want, you should use an arrow function:

```
(...args) => this.handleStuff('stuff', ...args) ≡ this.handleStuff.bind(this, 'stuff')
```

Comment: (There was [some discussion](https://github.com/tc39/proposal-bind-operator/issues/37) about supporting partial application)