# What does the double colon (::) mean in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6

What does the double colon in `::this.handleClick` do and how does it work? I'm guessing its an alternate syntax to `this.handleClick.bind(this)`

```
return <Map ref='map'
      center={this.state.latlng}
      zoom={13}
      onClick={::this.handleClick}
      onLocationfound={::this.handleLocationFound}
      length={4}>
      <TileLayer
        url='http://{s}.tile.osm.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png'
        attribution='&copy; <a href="http://osm.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors'
      />
      {marker}
    </Map>;
```

https://github.com/PaulLeCam/react-leaflet/blob/master/example/events.js#L39-L40

Comment: This was addressed here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31220078/javascript-double-colon-es7-proposal

But I believe the complex thing here is the {} wrapped around it. I think it is taking the named function and passing it as a properties of an object binded to the context of this

{handleClick: this.handleClick.bind(this)}

Comment: @DustinMoore the `{...}` is actually just JSX syntax [for using a JavaScript expression as an attribute value](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/jsx-in-depth.html#attribute-expressions).

Comment: Also binding handler functions etc inside render calls isn't the best way to bind. This will cause the bind call to be executed on the function every render cycle and return a new function every time. It's better to bind the functions (if needed) in the class constructor.    That way the function is bound once, and subsequent render cycles just refer to the same function ref.