# Call a method on its original containing object

Tags: javascript, oop, this

I have an object created with a constructor:

```
var mngr = new Manager();
```

It has a property `contacts` and a method `showContacts() { return this.contacts }`.

I also have another object, say, named `company` which runs some actions then in the end it needs to make `mngr` object run its `showContacts()`

I declare company and add a method from mngr to it:

```
var company = new Company({
    onFinish: mngr.showContacts
});
```

Now when I run the code from company object, it executes the function `onFinish` which is borrowed from `mngr.showContacts`, so it runs in context of the company, not mngr.

How do I make it perform the method on the mngr?

I have these variants:

```
var company = new Company({
    onFinish: mngr.showContacts.bind(mngr)
});
```

and:

```
var company = new Company({
    onFinish: function(){mngr.showContacts()}
});
```

Both seems not perfect.

How should I do it the right way?

Comment: How are they "not perfect" ? What do you want better ? BTW there's no such thing as an "original containing object", there's no link from a value to its assignements.

Comment: Well, if these are a normal way, then I am fine with it. Just seems like there must be a more beautiful way than these, but if not, then that's ok.

Comment: The thing is a value has no owner. There was a proposal in ES? to make it easier to write `mngr.showContacts.bind(mngr)` (something like `::mngr.showContacts` I think) but that's about all and it doesn't seem to be on its way.

Comment: ES7 proposes a [double colon syntax](http://stackoverflow.com/q/31220078/1529630).

Comment: @Oriol I think it's about dead, no ?

Comment: Ok, then which one of these two I proposed is preferred and why?

Comment: @SergeiBasharov: Both are totally fine. Arrow functions or binding the method on creating might *look* better if your care about that.

Comment: @DenysSéguret: No, why do you think so?

Comment: @Bergi It looked dead. I'm glad to hear it's on its way (I can't follow the ES discussion like you do, so I just trust you on that). Thanks.