# Bind proposal: Binding multiple arguments

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-next

There is a proposal that introduces a new way to [bind](http://blog.jeremyfairbank.com/javascript/javascript-es7-function-bind-syntax/). You can do for example

```
class Test {
    doIt() { ... }
}
let t = new Test();

doSomething(::this.doIt);
```

But what if `doIt` requires one or more params, how can I bind these too ?

```
::this.doIt(1,2,3)
```

Which executes the function immediately. Is there a way to do this?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31220078/javascript-double-colon-es7-proposal