# Webpack Sytax Error Unexpected "::" from React code

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack

I am trying to integrate [this react swipe module on github](https://github.com/voronianski/react-swipe). Everything has been going well until I began integrating [refs](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/more-about-refs.html) into my code. I am trying to call a react function from an `onClick`. Here is the [code snippet](https://github.com/voronianski/react-swipe/blob/gh-pages/demo/index.js) I am working with:

```
class Page extends Component {
    next() {
        this.refs.reactSwipe.next();
    }

    prev() {
        this.refs.reactSwipe.prev();
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div className="center">
                <h1>ReactSwipe.js</h1>
                <h2>Open this page from a mobile device (real or emulated).</h2>
                <h2>You can pass <a href="https://github.com/voronianski/swipe-js-iso#config-options">Swipe.js options</a> as query params.</h2>

                <ReactSwipe ref="reactSwipe" className="mySwipe" swipeOptions={swipeOptions}>
                    {paneNodes}
                </ReactSwipe>

                <div>
                    <button type="button" onClick={::this.prev}>Prev</button>
                    <button type="button" onClick={::this.next}>Next</button>
                </div>
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

The problem is that web pack is throwing a `Module build failed: SyntaxError: Unexpected token` on the `:` from the line:

```
<button type="button" onClick={::this.prev}>Prev</button>
```

What setting do I need to add to the webpack settings to allow for this `::`?
Or how can I go about calling a react function from the html `onClick` without the `::` function binding?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out after wandering across [this blog post](http://jamesknelson.com/using-es6-in-the-browser-with-babel-6-and-webpack/). The `::` is a [ES7 proposed shortcut](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31220078/javascript-double-colon-es7-proposal), and babel needs to be told to use the proposed parts of ES7.

So I installed the [stage 0 preset from babel](http://babeljs.io/docs/plugins/#stage-x-experimental-presets):

```
npm install babel-preset-stage-0 --save-dev
```

Then I updated my web-pack to recognize this:

```
module: {
  loaders: [
    {
      loader: "babel-loader",

      // Skip any files outside of your project's `src` directory
      include: [
        path.resolve(__dirname, "src"),
      ],

      // Only run `.js` and `.jsx` files through Babel
      test: /\.jsx?$/,

      // Options to configure babel with
      query: {
        presets: ['stage-0', 'react'],
      }
    },
  ]
}
```

The key part of this was the line:

```
presets: ['stage-0', 'react']
```