# What does `expand` mean in rxjs

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, rxjs

I'm reading [this code](https://github.com/alexanderGugel/ied/blob/master/src/install_cmd.js#L29) . It's my first encounter with RxJS.

Here is the relevant code:

```
const resolvedAll = updatedPkgJSONs
    ::map((pkgJson) => ({pkgJson, target: '..', isProd}))
    ::resolveAll(nodeModules, undefined, isExplicit)::skip(1)
    ::publishReplay().refCount()
```

I'm trying to guess the meaning of the above statement. But I'm stuck at `resolveAll` function.

Here is the `resolveAll` function:

```
export function resolveAll (nodeModules, targets = Object.create(null), isExplicit) {
    return this::expand(({target, pkgJson, isProd = false}) => {
        // more code
    })
}
```

What's the meaning of `this::expand`?
Is it the case that the parameters should match?
`({pkgJson, target: '..', isProd})` and `{target, pkgJson, isProd = false}`

I know there is [the document](https://github.com/Reactive-Extensions/RxJS/blob/master/doc/api/core/operators/expand.md). But I'm having a hard time relating the document to my example.

Comment: @DenysSéguret Hi, I do wish to have the question reopened. I'm still in the process of figuring it out by myself.  Not sure how long that'll take.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are quite a few features in this code:

- The `::` operator, known as the **[bind operator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31220078/javascript-double-colon-bind-operator)** will ensure that `this` is bound correctly.
- The `({arg1, arg2, arg3})` is a **destructuring operator**
- The `isProd = false` is a **default value** for the argument.

Specifically, what's happening here is that `this::expand` is a function that accepts a function as an argument (also known as a **higher order function**), the function `expand` accepts, accepts one Object argument, with properties named `target`, `pkgJson` and, optionally, `isProd` (which would default to false).