# Context visiability for function in js (React.js)

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Can you explain why react state is visible in fuction `handleFinishChange` and cannot be seen in `validationFinishTime`. Both are transfer to component `InputFieldForm`. 
Execution of this code lead to `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'finish' of undefined` in `validationFinishTime` when the field is changed in `input`.

Component **ShiftFormAdmin**

```
import React from 'react'
import {browserHistory} from 'react-router'
import Loading from './../form/loading.jsx'
import message from './../../constants/message';
import style from './../../constants/style';
import ErrorInformation from '../form/ErrorInformationForm.jsx';
import InputFieldForm from '../form/InputFieldForm.jsx';
import SelectFieldForm from '../form/SelectFieldForm.jsx';
import urls from './../../constants/urls'
import moment from 'moment';

export default class ShiftFormAdmin extends React.Component{

constructor(props){
    super(props)
    this.state = {
        box : {value : '', isValid : true},
        washerMan : {value : "", isValid : true},
        finish : {value : this.props.finish, isValid : true},
        start : '',
        availableWasherManList : [],
        boxCount : this.props.initData.boxCount,
        errorDisplay : style.DISPLAY_NONE,
        errorMessage : message.MESSAGE_DEFAULT_ERROR,
        isWasherMansDownloaded: false,
        isCurrentTimeDownloaded : false
    }
    this.handleSubmit = ::this.handleSubmit
    this.handleBoxChange = ::this.handleBoxChange
    this.downloadWasherMans = ::this.downloadWasherMans
    this.filterWasherMan = ::this.filterWasherMan
    this.downloadServerTime = ::this.downloadServerTime
    this.setStartTime = :: this.setStartTime
    this.handleFinishChange = ::this.handleFinishChange
}

handleFinishChange(e){
    this.setState({
        finish : {
            value : e.target.value,
            isValid : true
        }
    })
}

validationFinishTime(value){
    let result = false;
    console.log(this.state.finish.value)
    return result;
}

render(){
    let data = <Loading/>
    let boxCount = [];
    for(let i=1; i<=this.state.boxCount; i++){
        boxCount.push(i);
    }

    if(this.state.isWasherMansDownloaded && this.state.isCurrentTimeDownloaded) {
        data =
            <form className="form-horizontal" onSubmit={this.handleSubmit} id="shiftForm">

                <InputFieldForm
                    title="finish:"
                    name="finish"
                    onChange={this.handleFinishChange}
                    maxLength={5}
                    defaultValue={this.state.finish.value}
                    validation={this.validationFinishTime}
                    errorMessage="error"/>

                <div className="form-group">
                    <div className="col-sm-offset-2 col-sm-10">
                        <button type="submit" className="btn btn-success"> ADD
                        </button>
                    </div>
                </div>

            </form>
    }
    return(
            <div className="form-general">
                {data}
            </div>
    )
}
}
```

Class **FormInputField**

```
export default class FormInputField extends React.Component{

constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
        value : this.props.defaultValue ? this.props.defaultValue  : '',
        errorDisplay : st.DISPLAY_NONE,
        errorMessage : msg.MESSAGE_DEFAULT_ERROR,
    }
    this.validation = this.validation.bind(this);
    this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
    this.handleBlur = this.handleBlur.bind(this);
}

handleChange(e){
    let valid = this.validation(e.target.value.trim());
    if (this.props.onChange){
        this.props.onChange(e, valid)
    }
}

validation(value){
    let errorDisplay = st.DISPLAY_NONE;
    let errorMessage = '';
    let valid = true;

    if (this.props.notShow != true) {
        if (this.props.required && jQuery.isEmptyObject(value)) {
            errorMessage = msg.MESSAGE_FIELD_IS_REQUIRED;
            errorDisplay = st.DISPLAY_BLOCK;
            valid = false;
        } else if (this.props.maxLength && value.trim().length > this.props.maxLength) {
            valid = false;
            errorMessage = this.props.maxLength + msg.MESSAGE_MAX_LENGTH;
            errorDisplay = st.DISPLAY_BLOCK;
        } else if (this.props.validation && !this.props.validation(value.trim())) {
            valid = false;
            errorDisplay = st.DISPLAY_BLOCK;
            errorMessage = this.props.errorMessage;
        }
    }
    this.setState({
        value : value,
        errorDisplay : errorDisplay,
        errorMessage : errorMessage
    })

    return valid;
}

handleBlur(e) {
    this.validation(e.target.value.trim());
}

    render(){
        let data;
        let readonly = undefined;
        if (this.props.readonly){
            readonly = true
        }
        if(this.props.notShow != true){
            data =  <div className="form-group">
                <label htmlFor = {this.props.name} className="col-sm-2 control-label">{this.props.title}</label>
                <div className="col-sm-10">

                    <input name={this.props.name}
                           type="text" className="form-control"
                           id={this.props.name}
                           placeholder={this.props.placeholder}
                           value={this.state.value}
                           onChange={this.handleChange}
                           onBlur={this.handleBlur}
                           disabled={this.props.disabled}
                           readOnly = {readonly}
                    />
                </div>
            </div>
        }

    return(
        <div>
            {data}
        </div>
    )
}
```

}

Comment: Thanks for accepting my answer.  Can you confirm that both suggestions worked?  I just haven't seen bind syntax using `::` before :-)

Comment: No worries, found an answer: [Proposed ES6 shortcut for bind](http://stackoverflow.com/q/31220078/2902660)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Suggested solution: **Bind your event handler to the component
>   context/scope**:
>
> *(same as other statements in your constructor, but I haven't used before)*
>
> ```
> this.validationFinishTime = ::this.validationFinishTime
> ```
>
> OR (*the way I normally do this; again, within the constructor*):
>
> ```
> this.validationFinishTime = this.validationFinishTime.bind(this);
> ```

---

*Reasoning behind suggestion:*

This is a bit of a guess here because I haven't seen this syntax before (`this.handleFinishChange = ::this.handleFinishChange`) but I'm guessing that it binds the component's context of `this` to the method so the method `this.handleFinishChange` can reference things like `this.setState` and `this.state`.

`validationFinishTime` has no binding to the components context so when it references `this.state.finish`, there is no reference to `this.state` because the `this` refers to the context which it was called: which is the ***inline-event context*** of 'validation' on `<InputFieldForm/>`.