# Can I add the preset/plugin for double colon operator in create-react-app?

Tags: reactjs, create-react-app

I'm looking for a way but I can't find how do I add a preset or plugin for babel to transpile the [bind operator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31220078/javascript-double-colon-bind-operator).

Can I do this (and how), or you can't modify configuration on `create-react-app`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a [`transform-function-bind` Babel plugin](https://babeljs.io/docs/plugins/transform-function-bind/). However, `create-react-app` does not let you modify the underlying Babel configuration, so you would have to `npm run eject` (which is generally not recommended because you'd be losing the ability to update `react-scripts`). I would recommend ignoring this feature if you don't need it, and you may want to consider not using `create-react-app` (or ejecting) if you find it necessary.

Comment: Bummer.  What is your preferred way to do it?

Comment: I use arrow functions with property initializers for React handlers. These are both supported in `create-react-app`. https://babeljs.io/docs/plugins/transform-es2015-arrow-functions/ https://babeljs.io/docs/plugins/transform-class-properties/