# React event without binding this

Tags: reactjs, ecmascript-6, this

I'm currently in the process of learning React and I've come across something that seems weird in React's Getting Started guides.

I'm currently reading [this section](https://reactjs.org/docs/conditional-rendering.html).
There's this code sample:  https://codepen.io/gaearon/pen/QKzAgB?editors=0011

It showcases conditional rendering, that's not the point of my question though.
When they pass the HandleLogout/LoginEvent, they just pass this.HandleLoginEvent, without binding or using arrow functions, yet this code works perfectly, how does it work?

The piece of code I'm talking about is this:

```
let button = null;
    if (isLoggedIn) {
      button = <LogoutButton onClick={this.handleLogoutClick} />;
    } else {
      button = <LoginButton onClick={this.handleLoginClick} />;
    }
```

In the [previous section of the guides](https://reactjs.org/docs/handling-events.html) they explicitly state you have to use some method to bind the "this" in order for "this" not to be undefined when called from a child component, which makes sense.

Yet here "this" is somehow magically bound, how is it done?

Thanks, Avi.

**EDIT**: As Ori kindly pointed out, there's a bind call I've missed, problem solved :)

Comment: They are binding it in the constructor - `this.handleLogoutClick = this.handleLogoutClick.bind(this);`

Comment: Damn, you're right, I totally derped there. I don't know how to mark your answer as the right one, it's stuck as a comment :(

Comment: Binding in React is always a source of confusion :)

Comment: `onClick={()=>this.handleLogoutClick()}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.handleLoginClick = this.handleLoginClick.bind(this);
    this.handleLogoutClick = this.handleLogoutClick.bind(this);
    this.state = {isLoggedIn: false};
  }
```

When you do it this way you avoid forgetting to bind them when passing them all over the place.

Answer (score 4):

There are multiple ways to handle React binding pattern:

#### Bind in render

```
render() {
  return (
    <LogoutButton onClick={::this.handleLogoutClick} />
    {/* or */}
    <LogoutButton onClick={this.handleLogoutClick.bind(this)} />
  )
}
```

#### Bind in constructor

As shown in the codepen, which explains why you don't see binding in `render`.

```
constructor(props) {
  super(props)
  this.handleLoginClick = this.handleLoginClick.bind(this)
  // or
  this.handleLoginClick = ::this.handleLoginClick
}
```

#### Use arrow function

When you use arrow function to declare `handleLogoutClick`, the function uses lexical binding.

Normally in JS, the value of `this` is determined by how a function is called. But with ES6 arrow function, we are able to create function that behaves differently -
 it retains the `this` value of the enclosing lexical context, now we don't even have to call `bind`!

```
handleLogoutClick = () => {
  this.setState({isLoggedIn: false});
}
// and you can simply
onClick={this.handleLogoutClick}
```

---

Personally I definitely prefer arrow function, as it produces cleaner code, and I don't have to write that constructor just to bind stuffs. I can simply do:

```
class LoginControl extends React.Component {
  state = {isLoggedIn: false}

  //... other stuffs ...
}
```

As for binding in render (or arrow function *inside* render), you should always avoid that.

When working with `PureComponent`, binding in `render` will cause unnecessary re-rendering.

[Why Arrow Functions and bind in React’s Render are Problematic](https://medium.freecodecamp.org/why-arrow-functions-and-bind-in-reacts-render-are-problematic-f1c08b060e36)

Comment: What is the :: syntax? I know in Angular it means 1 time binding, what does it mean in react? What does it actually do?

Comment: @AviSasson: `::` has nothing to do with react. It's a stage 0 proposal for ECMAScript: https://github.com/tc39/proposal-bind-operator

Comment: @AviSasson This answer is short and easy to understand: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31220078/javascript-double-colon-bind-operator