# Meaning of ::this

Tags: javascript, reactjs, this, redux

I am trying to find out the meaning of this syntax with double colons and no matter how I google it nothing comes up.
Can anyone please tell me what ::this means as in for example:

```
 <MenuItem style={{'width': '21rem'}} eventKey="4" onSelect={::this.handleSignOut}>Sign out</MenuItem>
```

I am going through some React Redux codes on gitHub and there are full of these. I have some dispatch actions but they dont work inside the handleSignOut function and I dont know if it's to do with ::this. Thanks

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1520360/what-does-double-colon-do-in-javascript

Comment: it means `this.handleSignOut.bind(this)`