# How can I place Coldfusion code into a JavaScript variable

Tags: javascript, coldfusion, cfml

I would like to place some ColdFusion code into a javascript variable.  Please could someone advise how this can be done.

The ColdFushion code is as follows:

```
#LabelOverride::get('person')#
```

Comment: Just curious what the double colon `::` operator is.  Is that new to ColdFusion?

Comment: Looks like someone is trying to do a Bind operation. See: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1520360/what-does-double-colon-do-in-javascript/31180878 . If this is the intent, then no, ColdFusion does not work this way.

Comment: @JamesAMohler Thanks.  While the answer given by Sev Roberts is correct given the way the question was worded, it certainly will not work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A literal answer to your question would be something like:

```
<script>
var myJsVariable = '#EncodeForJavascript(LabelOverride::get("person"))#';
</script>
```

But if you're asking this question, I think there's a chance it's not going to behave quite how you might be hoping.